# Ruby "bucketize" an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have the following array:

```
a = (1..10).to_a
```

Is there a single in-built ruby (or rails) function that is capable or splitting the array into exactly N roughly equal parts while maintaining the order?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
a.bucketize(3)
=> [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
a.bucketize(5)
=> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

Hint: `each_slice` doesn't do this.

Also, I know I could write this function myself and open up the `Array` class or `Enumerable` module.

Thanks.

Comment: no, there is no such method

Comment: There isn't a single method but there is a single line way to do this. array.each_slice(3).map --- oops.  nope I am wrong. I misready what you were looking for.

Comment: Seems that really there is no method for that. So close your question if are not looking for a way to do it

Comment: Ended up using each_with_index + chunk to achieve the desired effect: https://gist.github.com/4402733

Comment: @Finbarr Then post it as an answer and after 48 hrs. you can accept it.

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu Why should the question be closed?

Comment: Close it or do what Andrew told you. I said to close because @tokland said there is no such method, so the answer with be a simple no

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu What did Andrew tell me to do? There's no reason to close this question; that a question has a simple answer doesn't negate the value of answering its logical followup. You have no reason to be short with me or be telling me what to do.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't think he read your username. I agree, I don't see why the question should be closed either.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it like this:

```
ary = (1..10).to_a

ary.each_slice((ary.length.to_f/3).ceil).to_a
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]

ary.each_slice((ary.length.to_f/5).ceil).to_a
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

It's not perfect, but it does come close:

```
ary = (1..9).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

ary.each_slice((ary.length.to_f/2).ceil).to_a
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]

ary.each_slice((ary.length.to_f/3).ceil).to_a
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

ary.each_slice((ary.length.to_f/4).ceil).to_a
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: I like it and it's definitely close. Unfortunately I have a hard requirement on there being exactly N buckets.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of task is best tackled using a functional approach. Here's a tail-recursive functional implementation (except for the unavoidable `<<` to accumulate efficiently on arrays):

```
class Array
  def bucketize(n, index = 0, acc = [])
    return acc if n <= 0 || size <= index
    n0 = ((size - index).to_f / n).ceil
    bucketize(n - 1, index + n0, acc << self[index, n0])
  end
end

(1..9).to_a.bucketize(3)
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
(1..10).to_a.bucketize(3)
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
(1..11).to_a.bucketize(3)
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
class Array
  def bucketize(n)
    return [] if (buckets = n.to_i) <= 0
    j = length / buckets.to_f
    result = each_with_index.chunk { |_, i| (i / j).floor }.map { |_, v| v.map(&:first) }
    result << [] until result.length == buckets
    result
  end
end
```

Examples:

```
a = (1..10).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a.bucketize(1)
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
a.bucketize(2)
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
a.bucketize(3)
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
a.bucketize(4)
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
...
a.bucketize(9)
=> [[1, 2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
...
a.bucketize(11)
=> [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], []]
```